# How to copy (from COL) and paste (to ROW) (replacing data in specific places)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a slight problemo. The code I have put together takes data from column A on `sheet(1)` and copies it (transposing it to row) to `sheet(2)`. Although, before I paste it in (here is the point when I have started recording a macro), I go "control+right" to find the first populated cell (in row 2 `(sheet(2)`) and then I select paste in the data transposing it and replacing the data that I already have there (to row).

The problem is that I have 1000 columns that I need to transpose in this way to rows (in each case row starts at various points on `sheet(2)`) and replace the old data. Can someone please advise? It would require some kind of loop (I know that).

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, lr As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1): Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

lr = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range("A2:A" & lr).Copy

With ws2
'I have recorded this part
ws2.Activate
Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End With
End Sub
```

Some screens for clarification:

[image]

Here ws2 where data begins at various points in each row (I need data from ws1 to be copied to ws2 and replace the data exactly where it begins in each row):

[image]

Comment: Where do you intend to paste the values in `ws2'? In the row  equal to copied column number? Then do all the columns in the first sheet have the same number of records?

Comment: @FaneDuru so the col A (ws1) data goes to row 2 (ws2), col B (ws1) to row 3 (ws2) and so on. The col's in A have a various number of records.

Comment: Then, try my answer code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testCopyTranspose()
 Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, lastCol As Long, LastCol2 As Long, i As Long

 Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1): Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

 lastCol = ws1.cells(1 & Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 For i = 1 To lastCol
    lr = ws1.cells(Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol2 = ws2.cells(i + 1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    ws1.Range(ws1.cells(2, i), ws1.cells(lr, i)).Copy
    ws2.cells(i + 1, LastCol2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                               SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: it is replacing the rows starting in column A (on ws2), while my need is to identify the first data point in each row (as there is data there) and paste in wherever each row is starting E.g. row 2 starts in LB2, row 3 in FX3, row 4 in LI4, row 5 in MF5 and so on.

Comment: @West Ray: What do you mean by " first data point "? Do you mean **the last empty column on that specific row** where the paste is executed?

Comment: the first data point in row 2 (ws2) starts in LB2 (and that's where I need to paste stuff from column A (ws1) - then I need stuff from the column B (ws1) to be pasted in FX3 on ws2). The issue is to (automatically) identify where the time-series begins in ws2 for each row (that's why I have recorded part of my macro to find the first instance of non-empty cell in row 2).

Comment: @West Ray: If is very difficult to understand something from what you try explaining, sorry... What "automatically" should mean for you? Based on what logic "identify where the time-series begins " to be done? You did not say anything about that... Can you explain now what algorithm to be applied in order to identify this "time-series" beginning?

Comment: Should I understand that on the row to paste there are empty cells until the column where so named "time-series" begins and there should the Paste take place?

Comment: So, my last assumption should be correct. Meaning that **the code will find the first column keeping data on the row to be pasted** and paste there. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If possible please edit your answer and I'll test it. Thx pal

Comment: @West Ray: I adapted the code starting from the above stated assumption. But cannot you confirm (or infirm) that what I assumed is what you want? I can adapt the code in any direction, but I would like to do that after I would be sure that I understand what you need.